# Software Defined Networking in Python Using Linux RYU Controller

Tags: network-programming, packet, sdn, network-traffic, ryu

I am actually working in a project SDN(Software Defined Networking) Based Project using python on linux(Ubuntu). Which actually works as a packet traffic monitor. All this work is shown on the cmd without GUI. I want a GUI in which we can see the animation of traffic like flow , or time delay , number of send or received packets.
Just need some help to do this.

## this is related to networking engineering or Net Centric Programming.

Answer (score 0):

I work with a project like do you want. We software is divided in backend and frontend. Backend runs an Openflow Controller that create and manage rules. We capture statistics of the rules and send to frontend application that shows this statistics in graphs. You can share the stats with frontend through Json or something like this. The Frontend Application can be developed in html/css/JavaScript.